# View not showing in didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, segue

**UPDATE**

After spending hours i found a solution for me. One problem was, that the segue wasn't shown after picking an image.

I have still a problem left, that the tabbar of the secondView isn't shown.. **But i can see an image NOOOW!!**

**But thank u all for your help!!!!**

Here my code:

//FirstView.m

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo{
    self->takenImage = image;
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    double delayInSeconds = 0.5;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ToSecondView" sender:self];
    });
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ToSecondView"]){
        SecondView *editViewController =
        (SecondView *)segue.destinationViewController;
        //editViewController.imageView.image = self->takenImage;
        [editViewController setMyImage:takenImage];
    }
}
```

//SecondView.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *myImage;
```

//SecondView.m in the viewDidLoad

```
self.imageView.image = _myImage;
```

---

**UPDATE**: 
For a better understanding, i post my rest of my code:

**FirstView**:

```
@interface FirstView : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>

@end


- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        SecondView *svc = [[ShowPicture alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil];
        [svc setMyImage:image];
        [self presentViewController:svc animated:YES completion:nil];
    }];
}
```

** SecondView**:

```
@interface ShowPicture: UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *imageView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *myImage;



-(void)viewDidLoad{
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(85, 90, 150, 150)];
    self.imageView.image = _myImage;
    [[self view] addSubview: imageView];
}
```

---

im getting really desperate. 
I want to pick with the UIImagePickerController a photo and want to display it in another view.
After trying different methods, im not able to show the second view, where the image should be placed.

My Code:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        SecondView *svc = [[SecondView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil];
        svc.imageView.Image = image;
        [self presentViewController:svc animated:YES completion:nil];
    }];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toSecondView"]){
        ShowPicture *showPicture =
        (ShowPicture *)segue.destinationViewController;
        //showPicture.imageView.image = self.imageChosen;

    SecondView Picture *cvc = [segue destinationViewController];
    cvc.image = newImage;
    }
}
```

When im clicking the Choose Btn, the screen goes to the view, where you can see the photo albums..

What am i doing wrong?? :/
Many Thanks

Comment: Have you set the `UIImagePickerController` delegate?

Comment: Are you using segue connection to navigate to ShowPicture view or through code? Because in imagePickerDelegate you are manually presenting that view, whereas you are also using prepareForSegue method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In here:

```
    ShowPicture *svc = [[ShowPicture alloc] initWithNibName:@"ShowPicture" bundle:nil];
    svc.imageView.Image = image;
```

`svc.imageView` object is not created yet.

For solution, you can define a property to `ShowPicture` as:

```
    @property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *myImage;
```

and change your picking delegate function to:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        ShowPicture *svc = [[ShowPicture alloc] initWithNibName:@"ShowPicture" bundle:nil];
        [svc setMyImage:image];
        [self presentViewController:svc animated:YES completion:nil];
    }];
}
```

and finally in `viewDidLoad` method of your `ShowPicture` `ViewController`:

```
self.imageView.image = _myImage;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers!
@Zaph: The UIImagePickerController delegate is set.

Comment: @Mrunal: The connection for the segue is set in the .storyboard
(Sry i posted both methods i tried..)

Comment: Thank u. I changed my code into your suggestions. But still the same..
Do i have to use the prepareForSegue method?

Comment: Segues are for `Storyboard` transitions, here you are presenting `ViewController` yourself; so not needed. Can you debug the code? Is `image` nil in pickercontroller delegate or what about _myImage in `viewDidLoad`. Or is `imageView` object is connected to the `UIImageView` in storyboard (is it nil?)?

Comment: I didnt connect imageView to the storyboard, i only set it programmatically.. So it is not an Outlet (if u mean this?!)  
Sry i am really new to programming apps.. I will try debug the code now

Comment: after getting an error for 
ShowPicture *svc = [[ShowPicture alloc] initWithNibName:@"ShowPicture" bundle:nil];

I changed this in:
UIStoryboard *sboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
ShowPicture *svc = [sboard instantiateInitialViewController];

I get now another error:
[UITabBarController setMyImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ffd64865f00
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITabBarController setMyImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ffd64865f00'

Is there no other way?? :(

Comment: You shouldn't use `instantiateViewController`, use : `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:"YOURVCIDENTIFIER"`. Without storyboards, it seems correct already. Also have you changed this line : `svc.imageView.Image = image;` to `[svc setMyImage:image];`?

Comment: Thank ugur, after getting rid of another problem i will try this.

Comment: Yes i changed everything.
Now im getting the error:
`'Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x7fd822ad7dd0>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'ShowPicture''` For some reason the compiler can't find **ShowPicture** but i checked this in the storyboard..

Comment: After research i found this: __Possibly related. In iOS7 [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier] is NOT instantiating the views from Interface Builder inside the view controller; but in iOS6 it did__